# Newbie Spring webflow end-state view error

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am customizing a CAS 4.0.0 with a war overlay.  I have added a x509 cert authenticator, and I want a custom error page.  I added this action-state:

```
<action-state id="startAuthenticate">
    <evaluate expression="x509Check" />
    <transition on="success" to="sendTicketGrantingTicket" />
    <transition on="warn" to="warn" />
    <transition on="error" to="certFailPage" />
</action-state>
```

and this end-state:

```
<end-state id="certFailPage" view="certFailPageView" />
```

and of course a certFailPageView.jsp with all the other views.  When I try and log in with a bad cert I am getting this error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [cas] in context with path [/cas] threw exception  
[Request processing failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown 
executing org.springframework.webflow.action.ViewFactoryActionAdapter@313c6dd3 in state 
'certFailPage' of flow 'login' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'] 
with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

However, If I change the the transition on="error" to a pre-defined page (like casBadHoursView) everything works fine.

What else do I need to do to make my jsp work?  I looked at the ViewResolver and it is a standard .jsp resolver.

I have been doing spring for a wile, but this is my first webflow exposure.  Is there some other place I need to register this view?

EDIT:  Full stack trace as requested:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [cas] in context with path [/cas] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing org.springframework.webflow.action.ViewFactoryActionAdapter@5a4b4352 in state 'certFailPage' of flow 'login' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.ServletMvcView.doRender(ServletMvcView.java:55)
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.render(AbstractMvcView.java:187)
at org.springframework.webflow.action.ViewFactoryActionAdapter.doExecute(ViewFactoryActionAdapter.java:40)
at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.EndState.doEnter(EndState.java:100)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:105)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:105)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.DecisionState.doEnter(DecisionState.java:51)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:105)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.start(Flow.java:535)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:366)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:222)
at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.launchExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:140)
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:193)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:125)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at com.github.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:63)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Was my solution of any help?

Comment: This question was over 2 years old,   I don't even work form them anymore, and I don't remember what fixed it.  (If i ever did) Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I had a problem with interpreting **view=""** attribute of <end-state> element.

**Instead of:**

```
<end-state id="certFailPage" view="certFailPageView">
```

**Change view attr to point to a particular .JSP file:**

```
<end-state id="certFailPage" view="certFailPageView.jsp">
```

**Here is some read for the View attribute (pulled from [XSD file](http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd)):**

```
Attribute : view
The name of a view to render as a final flow response. Is often not specified when the caller handles this flow outcome 
 and cares for the response. When specified, the value can be a flow-relative path to a view template: 
    priceForm.jsp
It can also be an evaluatable expression: 
    #{flowScope.myViewExpression}
The externalRedirect: prefix may be used to request a redirect to an external location, typically to interface with an 
 external system or controller. External redirect query parameters may be specified using #{expressions} that evaluate 
 against the request context. The supported formats for an encoded externalRedirect expression are: 
    externalRedirect:<servlet relative path>
    externalRedirect:contextRelative:<context relative path>
    externalRedirect:serverRelative:<server relative path>
    externalRedirect:<fully qualified http:// or https:// url>
For example: 
    externalRedirect:/hotels/index
    externalRedirect:http://someOtherSystem?orderId=#{order.id}
The flowRedirect: prefix may be used to redirect to another flow: 
    flowRedirect:myOtherFlow?someData=#{flowScope.data}
For exotic usages, you may plug in a custom ViewFactory bean you define: 
    #{myCustomViewFactory}
```